# Regex for shift+space

Tags: php

I have a string in UTF8 encoding that has many shift+space char between characters, I wanna replace them with space! How it can be done ?

Comment: You can replace all white space character with `preg_replace('~\h+~', ' ', $string);`

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, shift+space outputs an half-space

Comment: @Glavić, your regex matches something else!!

Comment: Shift+space depends entirely on the editor you're using. Figure out which of the [Unicode Spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-space_(punctuation)#Spaces_in_Unicode) it's creating, then replace *that*.

Comment: @DCoder, so how can i figure out the code ?:D

Comment: Look at the file in a hex editor, see what byte sequence corresponds to this space. It should match one of the character codes given in that page.

Comment: @DCoder, it's saved in DB, can i do that with copy/paste ?

Comment: MySQL? `SELECT HEX(field)` will show you the hex representation of that field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to just use a half space into a regexp:

```
$new = preg_replace("/ /", "-SPACE-", $yourstring);
```

provided that your source file is UTF8 coded (so that the thing between slashes in the regexp *is* actually a UTF8 halfspace), **and** your PHP has full UTF8 support (I believe all installations do since sometime after 5.0, but you never know...).

If you can't do that and need the UTF8 hex representation, you can do a hex dump of the file (or the shortest file you can with the character in it) and figure out what the codes are. You will see something like C3 A0 and you'll know that you can use `/...\xc3\xa0.../` as a regexp; remember that the backslash might need to be escaped.

Otherwise, you can maybe do something like this - I use another UTF8 character because I have no idea of what your editor uses as a "half-space" - you just prepare a string with that one character and decode it in PHP.

```
<?php
    $string = "é"; // THE SOURCE FILE MUST BE UTF8 CODED, OF COURSE...
    $hex    = bin2hex($string);
    $seq    = str_split($hex, 2);
    $search = "\\x".implode("\\x", $seq);

    print "The sequence is $search .\n";
?>
```

Now if you wanted to use it into a replacement regexp, you just plug it in:

```
    print preg_replace("/$search/", "(E)", "Déja vu");
```

outputs "D(E)ja vu" on my system.

**NOTE**: are you *sure* you need a regexp for that? `str_replace` might be faster and not require hex codes at all:

```
$new = str_replace(" ", " ", $old); // The first space is really a "half space"
```

**UPDATE**: you can do the above directly in MySQL too (make a backup of the DB first ;-) ):

```
UPDATE table SET field = REPLACE(field, '<A HALF SPACE HERE>', ' ');
```

(You might need to issue a `SET NAMES UTF8;` first, to be certain of the library character encoding).